# WPF HitTest Window thumb area?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `wpf` window, with a custom 'header'/'thumb' template.
Custom meaning - a couple of buttons are added to the window 'thumb'

the problem I'm trying to solve - is to 'turn off' window header double-click functionality (which maximizes the window by default)

What I did - I subscribed to `Window.PreviewMouseDoubleClick` event, 
and did the following

```
void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, someargs e){
    e.handled = true
}
```

My problem is - I only need to do this if the double click happened in the thumb area. (the code above disables double click for all the controls in the window)

So question how to reach the thumb element from code :

```
void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, someargs e){
   var pos = e.GetPosition((UIElement) sender);

   if (VisualTreeeHelper.HitTest(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, post))
          e.handled = true
}
```

Any ideas what I should put instead of the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ?

My window template looks like this 
[image]

I thought that this should work  - but I get back a null

```
 var z = this.Template.FindName("HeaderBorder", (FrameworkElement)sender);
```

Comment: Maybe grid name if you have there?

Comment: I added a screen if that helps.

Comment: Border is maybe problem here. You can wrap border with grid or canvas and use like this: `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvasName/gridName, post);`

Comment: work now with grid? I think it must because border have problem hit test. Is thin visual element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this case was quite simpe

```
 private void TimersCollectionWindow_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //Disable Double click inside the Title Bar
            var elem = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(FloatingContainerHeader, e.GetPosition(FloatingContainerHeader));
            if (elem != null) e.Handled = true;


        }
```

due to the fact that devexpress exposes 'FloatingContainerHeader' thingy :)